# How to add pending intent in notification BrightCoveOS

Tags: java, android, kotlin, brightcove

How to add pending intent when someone clicks in download notification in BrightCoveOS Android.

I used MediaDownloadable object for requesting download video in BrightCoveOS and I want to hide default notification provided by BrightCoveOS and want to add my own custom notification. For achieving this i used RequestConfig setNotificationVisibilty method but this didn't works.

And i also work with PlayerNotification manager but I'd didn't understand how to use this with BrightCoveOS android.

Here is my code (1st way downloading video without adding hiding notification code)

```
catalog.getMediaFormatTracksAvailable(video, (mediaDownloadable, bundle) -> {
         List<MediaFormat> list = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(MediaDownloadable.VIDEO_RENDITIONS);
         if (list != null) {
             brightCoveQualityHolders.clear();
             int bitrate = 0;
             for (MediaFormat media : list) {
                 brightCoveQualityHolders.add(new BrightCoveQualityHolder(media.width, media.height, media.bitrate));
                 if (media.height == 360) {
                     bitrate = media.bitrate;
                 }
                 String msg = "width " + media.width + " height " + media.height + " bitrate " + media.bitrate;
                 Log.d(TAG,msg);
             }
             catalog.setVideoBitrate(bitrate);

             getVideo(video, new OfflineCallback<>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(Video video1) {
                     if (video1.isClearContent()) {
                         videoListListener.downloadVideo(video1);
                     }
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {

                 }
             });
        });
```

2nd way (hiding notification (not work) with downloading work but some times not)

```
 catalog.findVideoByID(brightCoveVideoId, new VideoListener() {
 @Override
 public void onVideo(Video video) {
     mediaDownloadable = MediaDownloadable.create(context, video, downloadEventListener, new RequestConfig().setNotificationVisibility(RequestConfig.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN));
     mediaDownloadable.requestDownload();
     String name = allRecordModel.getTitle();
     video.getProperties().put(Video.Fields.NAME, name);
     progressDialog.show();
 }
```

});

Comment: Did you at least try, if so provide source code as well

Comment: Yes already tried please see my code above @FarkhodAbdukodirov

Comment: Any response @FarkhodAbdukodirov